# SQL Server statement explain

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please explain what the following statements mean. It's an assignment of local variables but I do not understand what `inserted` or `deleted` means?

```
select @ID = ID from inserted 

select @co_ID = co_ID from deleted
```

Thank you

Comment: What research have you done to understand it. What do you think it does? Clearly the above is from a trigger, so have you looked at the documentation on those? If not, why not (and I suggest that's where you start)?

Comment: *Side note, as this is from a `TRIGGER` it is severely flawed, as it assumed a DML statement can only effect one row. This is not true.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

INSERTED and DELETED are temporary, memory resident tables created by SQL Server for use (or misuse) within a DML trigger.

Inserts and updates copy new rows into INSERTED,
Deletes and updates copy old rows into DELETED.

It looks like this code is attempting to audit a change to a row of data - but will fail unless there is something else in the code path guaranteeing that only a single row will be updated.

Answer (score 0):

These statements mean that you have written a trigger in SQL Server that is not safe. The trigger assumes that only one row has been updated.  This is not safe because SQL Server calls triggers based on *groups* of rows.

If there is one row, then the parameters `@ID` and `@co_ID` are assigned values from that row.  If there are multiple rows being updated, then values  from arbitrary -- and perhaps different -- rows are assigned to the parameters.

Comment: Thank you so much for all the comments. The statement that i provided is from declaration part the trigger. I will keep in mind the inputs everyone has provided.